# SQL Show Max income of State by the County and display the County

Tags: sql

I am looking for a query on this database to return the expected result. Basically the state and then the county that has the highest income and then shows that income.

So far this is what I have:

```
SELECT a.STATE, a.COUNTY, b.MAX_INCOME
FROM table a
JOIN 
    (
      SELECT STATE, MAX(INCOME) MAX_INCOME
      FROM table
      GROUP BY 1
    ) AS b
ON b.STATE = a.STATE
WHERE b.MAX_INCOME= a.INCOME;
```

It returns multiple for IL because of the tie. Should I just do SELECT DISTINCT?

DATABASE:

| COUNTY | STATE | Income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| COOK | IL | 1000 |
| LAKE | IL | 1000 |
| DUPAGE | IL | 500 |
| JASPER | IN | 4000 |
| GREENE | IN | 1000 |

EXPECTED RESULT:

| STATE | COUNTY | INCOME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IL | COOK | 1000 |
| IN | JASPER | 4000 |

Thanks for any help!

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: Snowflake - DWH

Comment: What's the criteria to break tie?

Comment: Alphabetical would be the best

Comment: you can rank() them and take rank=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an installation of Snowflake to test this out, but it looks like "qualify" is what you're looking for:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008NrIYuSAN/whats-the-equivalent-of-distinct-on-in-snowflake-

The example used there is:

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  col4
FROM table
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1, col2) = 1
```

So based on the sorting of the subquery (i.e. make sure you sort the county ascending within it if you want the first alphabetically to show), you can have only the first row within there show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to get the first county with the maximum income:

```
select t1.state, (select t2.county from tbl t2 
        where t2.income = t1.i and t2.state = t1.state limit 1), t1.i from 
        (select t.state, max(t.income) i from tbl t group by t.state) t1
```

Comment: I am using snowflake and it does not allow subqueries like that